# Trying to make my spring batch job restartable

Tags: spring-batch

I am learning Spring Batch as I am developing one . The requirement is that ; If I have to kill the process in middle of processing; 
the batch should be able to pick up from where it's left off. Batch is reading data from database table based on a date range and processing 
and writing into another table when it's processed.

I have marked the job restartable = true. And for testing purpose when I kill the job (process) force fully in my local. 
I update the status of job_execution_id and step_execution_id to 'FAILED' using below sql

```
update batch_job_execution
set status = 'FAILED'
where job_execution_id = '226'

update batch_step_execution
set status = 'FAILED'
where step_execution_id = 1357
```

where batch job's last job execution id is 226 and job instance id is 198 and it's corresponding step execution is as 1357

But still the job throws below exception at

```
org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.java line number 131

jobExecution = jobRepository.createJobExecution(job.getName(), jobParameters);

Exception thrown 

org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException: A job execution for this job is already running: JobInstance: id=198, version=0, Job=[XYZ]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean$1.invoke(AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:181)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.createJobExecution(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:131)
    at com.XYZ.main.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:43)
```

Comment: You updated execution 226 but probably there is another execution that was left in a running state. The job repository [loops over all executions](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/support/SimpleJobRepository.java#L120) and does this check. Are you sure there are no other executions in a running state?

Comment: Thanks Hassine, I thought Job repository looks at only the job execution which is associated with the same job parameters.for example .. If my job takes date as job parameter and I am trying to restart my job which I ran yesterday then it will just look at job execution which ran yesterday. So I marked that as Failed.

Comment: Can anyone have any update on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: `I thought Job repository looks at only the job execution which is associated with the same job parameters`: you can have multiple executions with the same parameters (aka multiple job executions for the same job instance). Please list all job executions for job instance 198, you will see that one of them is still running, hence the exception `JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException`.